# What is tight NSPACE complexity of $ALT\text{-}SPACE(a(n),s(n))$?

Tags: space-complexity

According to [Ryan Williams's answer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/403/space-alternating-hierarchy/#tab-top) $ALT\text{-}SPACE(a(n),\log n)\subseteq NSPACE(a(n)\log n)$.

> Does there exist any better bound (for example something like $ALT\text{-}SPACE(a(n),\log n)\subseteq NSPACE(\log (a(n))\log n)$), or is it tight or an open problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's open, at least for the inclusion 
$ALTSPACE(\alpha(n),\log n)\subseteq NSPACE(f(n))$ with $\Omega(\log n)\leq f(n)\leq \alpha(n)^{o(1)}$. According to [Chandra, Kozen, and Stockmeyer](http://users.cis.fiu.edu/~giri/teach/5420/f01/papers/p114-chandra.pdf), we know
$$DTIME(n^k)\subseteq ALTSPACE(n^{2k},\log n)\subseteq \mathsf{P}.$$

Therefore if it is true, then $\mathsf{P}\neq \mathsf{NPSPACE}$ which is not known to be true. On the other hand, rejecting it will yield $\mathsf{P}\neq \mathsf{NL}$, which is also not known to hold.

Comment: Excuse me . I can't understand how $ALTSPACE(n^{2k},\log n)\subseteq P$. only things I know is $ASPACE(\log n)\subseteq P$  and the number of alternations is constant but if we replace the constant with a polynomial function how we could show that equation? can you explain a little more? Thank you again.

Comment: @MohsenGhorbani The proof of $ASPACE(\log n)\subseteq P$ works with any  number of alternations, not only for constants. On the other hand with $s(n)=O(\log n)$ space there are at most $2^{O(s(n))}$ possible configurations, and thus $2^{O(s(n))}=n^{O(1)}$ alternations.